# Cannot download Maven dependencies from GitLab Package Registry

Tags: java, spring, gitlab-ci

I have one java-spring application with 2 maven dependencies in different repositories, but in the same group. I used gitlab-ci to deploy the jar in 2 project package registries, but I cannot retrieve them (I can with only one dependency, setting its project repo, in the spring application pom)
.
For the 2 dependencies, I wrote the same `ci-settings.xm`l:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
                <property>
                    <name>Job-Token</name>
                    <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
                </property>
            </httpHeaders>
        </configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

with the same `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
deploy:
 image: maven:3.6-jdk-11
 script:
  - 'mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml'
 only:
  - master
```

In the the pom.xml for the 1st dependency (sp1) I have:

```
<groupId>ch.myCompany.dep</groupId>
<artifactId>sp_1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/GROUP_ID/-/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/SP1_REPO_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/SP1_REPO_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And in the the pom.xml for the 2st dependency (sp2) I have:

```
<groupId>ch.myCompany.dep</groupId>
<artifactId>sp_2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/GROUP_ID/-/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/SP2_REPO_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/SP2_REPO_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

In the spring application, I set the 2 artifacts as a dependency but I'm not able to retrieve them. This is part of the pom.xml:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>ch.myCompany.dep</groupId>
<artifactId>sp_service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sp_service</name>
<description>Service Layer for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.myCompany.dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>sp_1</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.myCompany.dep</groupId>
        <artifactId>sp_2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/GROUP_ID/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dependencies' pom.xml `distributionManagement` section, you are using the correct url:

```xml
<url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/GROUP_ID/-/packages/maven</url>
```

However, in your spring application pom.xml `repositories` section, the url is incorrect:

```xml
<url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/GROUP_ID/packages/maven</url>
```

You're missing `/-/` between `GROUP_ID` and `packages`.

Comment: can both dependency projects be spring boot project as well ?

Comment: @valik As long as you deploy the spring boot projects as maven artifacts (using `mvn deploy` step), you can declare them as a maven dependency in another project. However, spring boot is usually used to set up an entire web server, whereas dependencies tend to be made up of libraries. You may want to consider extracting some common libraries into a separate project.